# Superposition principle and fixed positions charges

Tags: electrostatics, charge, superposition, coulombs-law, linear-systems

I am trying to understand this sentence of my course:

> The superposition principle implies that the net force between any two
> charges is independent of the presence of other charges. This is true
> if the charges are in fixed positions.

It is the very last sentence of this chapter and i am realizing that i missed something important because i don't understand why the above statement is true if the charges are in fixed positions? what happens if they are not in fixed positions? Furthermore, does it mean that if the charges are not at fixed positions, the superposition principle cannot be applied? Finally what if they are moving in the same direction and at the same speed?